# Failed on OIDC vault group

Tags: google-oauth, openid-connect, hashicorp-vault

I am building a vault with oidc enabled. I have created oidc configuration and roles including group and group alias. But it turns out that I am facing an issue related to

> failed to fetch groups: Get "https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups?alt=json&fields=nextPageToken%2Cgroups%28email%29&prettyPrint=false&userKey=xxxxxxxxxxxx": oauth2: cannot fetch token: 401 Unauthorized Response: { "error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested." }

I have granted the access to roles below :

```
1.https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly
2.https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly
```

Here is the command that I used:

```
vault write auth/oidc/config -<<EOF
{
    "oidc_discovery_url": "https://accounts.google.com",
    "oidc_client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "oidc_client_secret": "xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
    "default_role": "noaccess",
    "provider_config": {
        "provider": "gsuite",
        "gsuite_service_account": "/var/vault/sa.json",
        "gsuite_admin_impersonate": "xxxx.xxxxx@xxxxx.com",
        "fetch_groups": true,
        "fetch_user_info": true,
        "groups_recurse_max_depth": 5
    }
}
EOF

vault write auth/oidc/role/noaccess \
    allowed_redirect_uris="https://xxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxx.com/ui/vault/auth/oidc/oidc/callback" \
    allowed_redirect_uris="http://localhost:8250/oidc/callback" \
    user_claim="sub" \
    policies= "" \
    ttl=1h \
    groups_claim="groups" 

vault write identity/group name="xxxx-xxxx@xxx.xx.xx" type="external" \
        policies="reader" \
        metadata=responsibility="reader"

export GROUP_ID="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"

vault auth list -format=json | jq -r '."oidc/".accessor' > accessor.txt

vault write identity/group-alias name="xxxx-xxx@xxx.xx.xx" \
        mount_accessor=$(cat accessor.txt) \
        canonical_id="$GROUP_ID"
```

If I remove the `groups_claim="groups"` the oidc is working but the policies given to the group is not applied.